# Flutter ListTile title name from json

Tags: android, json, flutter

I am trying to display both names of a person as a title in listtile flutter. This is the sample json file

```
var users = const [
    {
       "first_name": "melissa",
       "last_name": "fleming",
       "phone_number": "0740-304-475"
    },
    {
      "first_name": "christoffer",
      "last_name": "christiansen",
      "phone_number": "05761325"
    },
    {
      "first_name": "valtteri",
      "last_name": "pulkkinen",
      "phone_number": "041-829-79-61"
    }
]
```

This is the flutter code

```
 @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        centerTitle: true,
        title: Text(
          "List of Customers",
      ),
      
      body: ListView.separated(
        itemCount: users.length,
        separatorBuilder: (context, index) => Divider(),
        itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
          var user = users[index];
          return ListTile(
            title: Text(user['first_name']),
            isThreeLine: true,
          );
        },
      ),
    );
  }
```

How can I pass both names to this part

```
title: Text(user['first_name']),
```

Comment: what you get for `user['first_name']`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use for in loop and store the value in a String

```
for(var i in users){
String name = i['first_name'] + " "+ i['last_name'];
print(name);}



ListView.separated(
    itemCount: users.length,
    separatorBuilder: (context, index) => Divider(),
    itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
      var user = users[index];
      return ListTile(
        title: Text(name),
        isThreeLine: true,
      );
    },
  ),
```

Answer (score 0):

there are two ways you can do it.

First Approach : if you want to show full name as title :

```
title : Text("$users[0]['first_name'] $users[0]['last_name']")
```

Second Approach : if you want to show first name and last name separately use subtitle :

```
ListTile(
  leading: const Icon(Icons.flight_land),
  title: const Text($users[0]['first_name']),
  subtitle: Text($users[0]['last_name']),
  onTap: () { /* react to the tile being tapped */ }
)
```

Comment: the first approach prints the whole json file

Comment: you need use index if you only want particular data by index. I have edited my answer,